# Meaning of these signs (Characters identified: 宁静)

Tags: translation, meaning, character-identification

Could someone please tell me what these signs mean, the OCR couldn't read them.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I self-answer "What does this say?"](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/36144/how-do-i-self-answer-what-does-this-say)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word is [宁静](http://xh.5156edu.com/html5/338651.html) [níngjìng]:

> ①安定 (calm)；安宁 (tranquil)：宁静四海｜地方宁静。
>   ②安静 (quiet)；平静 (peaceful)：心情宁静｜宁静的灯光｜宁静的月夜。